# How to read text from a website in Python

Tags: python, html

I would like to read some of the information from this website: http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/beigebook/beigebook201301.htm

I have the following code, and it properly reads the HTML source

```
def Connect2Web():
    aResp = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/" + 
    "beigebook/beigebook201301.htm")

    web_pg = aResp.read()

    print web_pg
```

I am lost on how to parse this information, however, because most HTML parsers require a file or the original website, whereas I already have the information I need in a String.

Comment: "most HTML parsers require a file or the original website" False. Most of them operate simply on HTML.

Comment: Look into [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We started with BS some time ago but eventually moved to lxml

```
from lxml import html
my_tree = html.fromstring(web_pg)
elements = [item for item in my_tree.iter()]
```

So now you have to decide which elements you want and you need to make sure that the elements you keep are not children of other elements that you decide you want to keep  for instance

```
<div> some stuff
<table>
<tr>
<td> banana </td>
</tr>
<table>
some more stuff
</div>
```

The html above table is a child of div so everything in table is contained in div  so you have to use some logic to keep only those elements whose parents are not already kept

Answer (score 1):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(web_pg)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like jQuery use [pyQuery](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyquery)

start with

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

d = pq(web_pg)
```

or even

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq

d = pq(url="http://www.federalreserve.gov/monetarypolicy/beigebook/beigebook201301.htm")
```

Now d is like the $ in jQuery:

```
p = d("#hello") # get element with id="hello"
print p.html() # print as html

p = d('#content p:first') # get first <p> from element with id="content"
print p.text() # print as text
```

Comment: ..strong upvote - pyquery is the easiest solution for painless html munging..if the direct `pq(url=...)` fails (f.e. lxml complaining about unsupported "**Unicode strings with encoding declaration**"), fetch the file first via `urllib.urlopen(url).read()`, then feed it to pyquery.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use RE--Regular expression to parse this information (in fact it can parse all text), it is **faster** than BeautifulSoup and others, but in the same time, regular expression is harder to learn than others

Here is [DOCUMENT](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

example:

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'<p>(.*?)</p>')
content = r'<p> something </p>'
data = re.findall(p, content)
print data
```

it print:

```
[' something ']
```

This example can extract content which between `<p>` and `</p>`

It's just a very simple example to regular expression.

It's very import to use regular expression because it can do more thing than others.

So, just learn it!

Comment: Thank you, RegEx is definitely something I plan on learning at some point